# Python - Creating a file works in PyScriptor but not IDE?

Tags: python, permissions

When I try to create a new file in PyScriptor using the following code, it works perfectly with no errors but when I use the same code outside of PyScriptor for example in the IDE, it just flashes an error and closes.

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
file.write("hello")
file.close()
```

I cannot get the errors because the error message lasts for less than a second before the Interpreter closes.

Help to figure out why this happens and how to fix it is appreciated.

I am using Python version 2.5.3.0 on windows 7 if this helps.

[EDIT]

Thanks to kirbyfan64sos  and JAB for helping me get the errors. It turns out that Python does not have permission to open any file at all (r, w, a etc) yet Pyscriptor has all these permissions so the question still remains: why are they be different and how do i fix them?

I know that it is not the permissions of the file itself otherwise it would not work in Pyscriptor.

[ERROR CODE]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "IDE File test.py", line 1, in <module>

    file = open("file.txt", "w")

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "file.txt"
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an error in PyScripter. However, try pasting the lines at the same indent to see the error, esp the 1st line.

Comment: To get the error message, run the script from the command line, i.e. `python /path/to/script.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are the permissions of wherever your IDE is running in are not writable by you.

To check:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
```

I'm quite certain that you'll find the current path will be different depending on which IDE you run from. Most IDEs have a setting for which path you'll start at. You can also get around that by using `os.chdir` to change to your home directory (or giving an absolute path to `open()`, e.g. `open('/home/wayne/test.txt', 'w')`)

Comment: I changed the code to use the absolute directory using C:/Users/... and it now works fine, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `"w"` instead of `"W"`. `"W"` is an invalid file mode. Also, `file.close` should be `file.close()`, as `file.close` will just return the `file` object's `close` method and won't actually call it.

Note that if you start the interpreter from inside the command shell, the shell won't close when an error is raised so you'll be able to see it there. The same applies to using IDLE.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to remember the code off by heart and obviously got it wrong, I have made the changes in the original post. I checked to make sure that wasn't the problem in the actual file and I had it correct.